# Auto divide and sum values in Jquery

Tags: jquery, math

***Please refer to the sample link first to understand my issue.***

first im dividing a value and displaying each divided values into input text field.

you can see the sample here.. http://fahidmohammad.in/demo/sample/

in the sample link - - the total is the amount to be divided and number of installment is the number of split.

I know what you might be thinking...what exactly i need right??

Here comes the second stage of the process:

now i have the splits, what i need actually is, if i change the value form any of the splitted input the next value or the remaining should auto sum with the total amount.

eg...

```
Total Amount = 9000
Number of installment = 3

Split1 = 3000
Split2 = 3000
Split3 = 3000
```

if i decide to change `split1 to 4000` then the remaining splits should auto sum.

eg..

```
Split1 = 4000
Split2 = 2500 [auto sum]
Split3 = 2500 [auto sum]
```

Mathematically i know the process but how do i accomplish this in jquery coz the number of splits may vary upon the user input.

What is the right method to follow???

Comment: just make 'readonly' your created inputs. :)

Comment: uffff.... this will be H.A.R.D. You'll need to check what elements was edited, than substract it's value from the total (or remaining total) and refresh the values on the 'untouched' inputs. Than you'll have to stop that part after 3 fields are 'untouched.' Why? couse: while you're changing one you have to divide the result to 2 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what you need to do...

i'd suggest to first start by adding elements like

```
var numInst = $('input[name="ni"]').val();
var total = $('input[name="ta"]').val();
var payment = total / numInst;

for(var i = 0; i < total; i++){
    $('<input/>').attr({
        'type' : 'text',
        'name' : 'sum[]'
    }).val(payment).addClass('installment').appendTo('#inner');
}
```

i'm freehanding this so give or take some errors...but that's a much more efficient way to do it rather than appending strings as html.

for your installment onchange event:

```
$('.installment').change(function(){
    var numInst = $('input[name="ni"]').val();
    var total = $('input[name="ta"]').val();
    var otherPayment = (total - $(this).val()) / (numInst - 1);

    $(this).addClass('dontChange');

    $.each($('.installment'),function(i, val){
        if(!($(this).hasClass('dontChange')){
            $(this).val(otherPayment);
        }
    });

    $(this).removeClass('dontChange');
});
```

like i said, i freehanded all this, but i think the logic is solid.  just add a class to the one that was manually changed temporarily, then loop through the installment class text boxes and change the value to equal the total, minus the value that was manually entered, divided by 1 less payment that what ni equals.

the only problem i might foresee is that without setting a flag to those boxes that have been manually changed, any changes will be overwritten if the user changes another installment boxes.

easy fix would be to move the $(this).removeClass('dontChange'); line from the installment onchange function to the end of your ni and ta onchange handler.  just change $(this) to $('.installment')

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is figuring out which split fields the user wants to purposefully over-ride. From a UX perspective, I'd suggest that the split fields be text and adding a checkbox that the user would explicitly check. Something like 'custom value'.  It'd end up looking like this if a person decided to customize the second field:

```
split 1 =  2000   [ ] enter custom value
split 2 = [4000]  [X] enter custom value
split 3 =  2000   [ ] enter custom value
```

You would then know a) the number of splits (based on the value in the installments input) and b) the number of splits that the user has chosen to set to a custom value.

The math is then TOTAL AMOUNT - (each custom field added together) / remainder split fields.

Comment: you confused me even more...
it doesn't helped... ;(

Comment: well i can place a identifier to determine which field is being edited. that doesn't solve the problem here. i need to re-calculate the dynamically generated input fields. which i the most unknown part to me.

Comment: You need to fire the re-calculation via an event. Something has to trigger it. It's up to you which event would fire that. It could be keydown, on change, on blur, or perhaps on click of a 'recalculate' button.

Comment: triggering the re-calculate is not the problem here. its how can i manage to share the remaining amount to the active splits.

Comment: You know the total (a = TOTAL AMOUNT). You know how much of that is set by the user (b = fields marked ENTER CUSTOM VALUE). And you know the number of remaining fields that need to share the rest (c = fields NOT marked ENTER CUSTOM VALUE). So the equation is (a-b)/c = the value you need to enter into each of the 'c' fields.